# Dealing with categorical predictors which aren't presented in trained decision tree classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-structures, decision-tree

I am creating my own DecisionTreeClassifier Python class for dataset with categorical predictors only. There is a [dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/dataset/73/mushroom) which is perfectly suits for the task. Here is my implementation of that classifier:

InformationEntropy - provides `gain_ratio_X(pd.DataFrame, str)` and remembers: predictors columns (and values), output class label (and values).

```py
class InformationEntropy:
  def __init__(self, df, y_label):
    self.y_label = y_label
    self.y_classes = set(df[y_label].to_list())
    self.X_values = dict()
    for label in df.columns:
      if label != y_label:
        self.X_values[label] = set(df[label].to_list())

  def freq(self, df, C_j):
    return df.loc[df[y_label] == C_j].shape[0]

  def info(self, df):
    if df.shape[0] == 0:
      return 0

    result = 0
    for y_class in self.y_classes:
      freq_c_div_df = self.freq(df, y_class) / df.shape[0]
      if freq_c_div_df == 0:
        continue
      result -= freq_c_div_df * np.log2(freq_c_div_df)
    return result

  def info_X(self, df, X_label):
    if df.shape[0] == 0:
      return 0

    result = 0
    for attr in self.X_values[X_label]:
      df_i = df.loc[df[X_label] == attr]
      if df_i.shape[0] == 0:
        continue
      result += df_i.shape[0] * self.info(df_i)
    result /= df.shape[0]
    return result

  def split_info_X(self, df, X_label):
    result = 1e-9
    for attr in self.X_values[X_label]:
      df_i = df.loc[df[X_label] == attr]
      if df_i.shape[0] == 0:
        continue
      df_i_div_df = df_i.shape[0] / df.shape[0]
      result -= df_i_div_df * np.log2(df_i_div_df)
    return result

  def gain_ratio_X(self, df, X_label):
    return (self.info(df) - self.info_X(df, X_label)) / self.split_info_X(df, X_label)
```

`DecisionTreeNode` - provides `predict` and `predict_proba` methods, describes dataframe state at specific tree node.

```py
class DecisionTreeNode:
  def __init__(self, parent_attribute = None, parent_attribute_value = None, attribute = None, entropy = 0.0, samples_count = 0):
    self.parent_attribute = parent_attribute
    self.parent_attribute_value = parent_attribute_value
    self.attribute = attribute
    self.entropy = entropy
    self.samples_count = samples_count
    self.samples = dict()
    self.probability = dict()
    self.prediction = None
    self.children = list()

  def predict(self, X):
    if len(self.children) == 0: # node is a leaf
      return self.prediction

    for child in self.children:
      if X[self.attribute] == child.parent_attribute_value:
        return child.predict(X)

  def predict_proba(self, X):
    if len(self.children) == 0: # node is a leaf
      return self.probability

    for child in self.children:
      if X[self.attribute] == child.parent_attribute_value:
        return child.predict_proba(X)
```

DecisionTree - classifier, builds decision tree by `DecisionTreeNode` elements, provides `predict` and `predict_proba` as root element `DecisionTreeNode.predict` and `DecisionTreeNode.predict_proba`.

```py
class DecisionTree:
  def __init__(self, max_leaf_entropy = 0.0, max_leaf_samples = 1):
    assert (max_leaf_entropy > 0) or (max_leaf_samples > 0), "Entropy ratio and samples count to define leaf can't be 0 at once"

    self.decision_tree_node = None
    self.max_leaf_entropy = max_leaf_entropy
    self.max_leaf_samples = max_leaf_samples
    self.info_entropy = None

  def build_tree(self, df, TreeNode):
    if df.shape[0] == 0:
      return

    best_attr = None
    best_ratio = 0
    for attr in self.info_entropy.X_values:
      ratio = self.info_entropy.gain_ratio_X(df, attr)
      if best_ratio < ratio:
        best_attr = attr
        best_ratio = ratio

    TreeNode.attribute = best_attr
    TreeNode.entropy = best_ratio
    max_samples_count = 0
    for y_class in self.info_entropy.y_classes:
      TreeNode.samples[y_class] = df.loc[df[self.info_entropy.y_label] == y_class].shape[0]
      TreeNode.probability[y_class] = TreeNode.samples[y_class] / df.shape[0]
      if max_samples_count < TreeNode.samples[y_class]:
        max_samples_count = TreeNode.samples[y_class]
        TreeNode.prediction = y_class
    TreeNode.samples_count = df.shape[0]

    if (TreeNode.entropy > self.max_leaf_entropy) and (TreeNode.samples_count > self.max_leaf_samples):
      for attr in self.info_entropy.X_values[best_attr]:
        df_loc = df.loc[df[best_attr] == attr]
        if df_loc.shape[0] > 0:
          child = DecisionTreeNode()
          child.parent_attribute = best_attr
          child.parent_attribute_value = attr
          TreeNode.children.append(child)
          self.build_tree(df_loc, TreeNode.children[-1])

  def fit(self, df: pd.DataFrame, y_label: str):
    self.info_entropy = InformationEntropy(df, y_label) 
    self.decision_tree_node = DecisionTreeNode()
    self.build_tree(df, self.decision_tree_node)
    return self

  def predict(self, X_test):
    y_test = []
    for i in range(X_test.shape[0]):
      y_test.append(self.decision_tree_node.predict(X_test.iloc[i]))
    return y_test

  def predict_proba(self, X_test):
    y_test = []
    for i in range(X_test.shape[0]):
      y_test.append(self.decision_tree_node.predict_proba(X_test.iloc[i]))
    return y_test
```

There is an obvious problem in `DecisionTreeNode.predict` (and `_proba`) that frequently happens because of `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split` when it choses train part that doesn't cover every value of all predictors. In that case,

```py
for child in self.children:
  if X[self.attribute] == child.parent_attribute_value:
    return child.predict(X)
```

can't find such child and actually returns nothing.

I don't want to encode categorical options to additional columns, so I can't imagine any reasonable solution except this one:

*Changing DecisionTreeNode.predict (and _probe)*

```py
def predict(self, X):
  for child in self.children:
    if X[self.attribute] == child.parent_attribute_value:
      return child.predict(X)
  
  # happens if node is a leaf or there's no suitable child
  return self.prediction
```

Now it returns inaccurate result which is better then return nothing, but it can happen at the very begining of the tree and prediction can be very irrelevant.

I am wondering if there is more proper solution.